# call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged from different activity

Tags: android, listview, socket.io, listadapter

I'm fairly new to android programming. I'm using  [socket.io](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIuZOB0-zKAhWVCo4KHdgHBf0QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsocket.io%2Fblog%2Fnative-socket-io-and-android%2F&usg=AFQjCNFEHYidhPhiQkw7-UmAwrq56xP7FA&sig2=B4oeYw4lIY5B3yk8LRH5Sw)  to build a basic chat application in androd. I'm using a singleton class to share data between two activities. I have a list adapter in the second activity and I want to  call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from the first activity when I receive data from the server. Is this possible?

In the first activity:

```
mSocket.on("New", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) args[0];
        Singleton.getInstance().AddMsg(temp);
        // I want to call the adapter defined in the second activity here. i.e. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

A few points to note:

**adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** is working well if I call it from 2nd activity.

1st activity runs only once when the application is launched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can do that by **Broadcast**

```
    mSocket.on("New", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) args[0];
            Singleton.getInstance().AddMsg(temp);
            // I want to call the adapter defined in the second activity here. i.e. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


         // send broadcast that is added something
        Intent intent = new Intent("Added_something");
        //intent.putExtra("current speed", "102.4");
        //intent.putExtra("latitude", "12.2342342");
        //intent.putExtra("longitude", "12.21124");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);


        }
    });
```

> In **SecondActivity**

register for `BroadcastReceiver` like below

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(message,
                new IntentFilter("Added_something"));
```

> Declare `BroadcastReceiver`

```
    private BroadcastReceiver message = new BroadcastReceiver() {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // refresh your adapter from SecondAdapter itself
        }
    };
```

### Refer this [good tutorial for local brodacast](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/)

Comment: Welocme :) , Glad to help you . Do vote up as well :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in calling notifyDataSetChanged() from the first activity as ListView is in Second Activity. You should transfer the data from first activity to second activity whenever you open the second activity through intents and then call notifyDataSetChanged() from the second activity itself.

Reason for not calling from first activity is that you don't know if the second activity will be visible or not. Only change adapter data when the corresponding list is visible on the screen. Don't modify the adapter from other activities.

Comment: Hi, I start some background process in the first activity and hence I want to notify the second sctivity when I recieve new data.I'm maintaining all the data in a singleton class.The data is updating well.The only problem I face is notifying the adapter.and I think starting the second activity everytime I receive data is quite expensive(I'm very new to android so I'm assuming this.).Please correct me if this is bad practice.Thank you for your answer

Comment: You don't need to start the second activity every time. Just maintain the data in the singleton and whenever second activity is launched just retrieve the stored data from the singleton as you know already that you have stored the data in the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

adding to @JyotmanSingh you can try to create a socket service and a callback handler in your activity to perform the updates...

Comment: Add this as comment section .